# rpy2 installation results in UnsatisfiableError in conflict with blas

Tags: python, conda, rpy2, blas

I want to install `rpy` into my conda installation, but I get the UnsatisfiableError

```
$ conda install rpy2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - blas
  - conda-forge/linux-64::statsmodels==0.10.1=py37hc1659b7_1 -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - conda-forge/noarch::descartes==1.1.0=py_3 -> matplotlib -> numpy -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - conda-forge/noarch::mizani==0.6.0=py_0 -> matplotlib[version='>=3.1.1'] -> numpy -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - conda-forge/noarch::patsy==0.5.1=py_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.4.0'] -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - conda-forge/noarch::plotnine==0.6.0=py_0 -> descartes[version='>=1.1.0'] -> matplotlib -> numpy -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - mkl_fft -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - mkl_random -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - numpy -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - numpy-base -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - pkgs/main/linux-64::matplotlib==3.1.1=py37h5429711_0 -> numpy -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - pkgs/main/linux-64::pandas==0.25.2=py37he6710b0_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> blas==1.0=mkl
  - scipy -> blas==1.0=mkl
```

I have tried other conda installations (like using conda-forge) but I still get UnsatisfiableError - though with different details.

Funny enough, installing it with pip worked...

I have the conda installation

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
ca-certificates           2019.9.11            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.6               he372182_0    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_3    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5             he1b5a44_1004    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            he4413a7_1000    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               he983fc9_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hc5be6a0_1002    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3            h6f030ca_1002    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.14.5               h36ae1b5_0    conda-forge
icu                       58.2              hf484d3e_1000    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      243  
jpeg                      9c                h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37hc9558a2_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libiconv                  1.15              h516909a_1005    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hed695b0_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libuuid                   2.32.1            h14c3975_1000    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h13577e0_2    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h5429711_0  
mizani                    0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      243  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37hd6b4f25_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.17.2           py37haad9e8e_0  
numpy-base                1.17.2           py37hde5b4d6_0  
openssl                   1.1.1c               h516909a_0    conda-forge
palettable                3.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.2           py37he6710b0_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.43                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0  
plotnine                  0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37hcca6a23_4    conda-forge
python                    3.7.4                h265db76_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h52cfd70_2    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h7c811a0_0  
setuptools                41.4.0                   py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
sqlite                    3.30.1               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37hc1659b7_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h516909a_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0  
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h14c3975_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

Comment: Hmm, that error message seems pretty useless - i.e., everything it shows looks compatible (`blas==1.0=mkl`). Consider posting it to [the GitHub repo issues](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues), since this seems like a bug, either in not correctly presenting the incompatibilities, or failing to install when there is no problem. I would perhaps try recreating the env with only Conda Forge builds.

Comment: Versions of rpy2 on conda are often quite a bit behind. Try to use pip (or other means to install from pypi) if you can.

Comment: @Igautier: Thanks for the pointer. Using pip is what I did, but now I don't get a window: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58628942

Comment: A fair share of rpy2 issue reports come from conda users, and among them a sizeable fraction was traced to the way dependencies were handled through conda packaging. I am unfortunately not very knowledgeable about conda, and I couldn't provide much advice other than asking whether you could install R for example through your system's packaging system. The continuous builds for `rpy2` on Travis set up the test system this way.

Comment: @Igautier: R is already locally installed through my system's packaging system and I am happy to use that installation. How do I do that? Youm mention "Travis". Could you link to this documentation, please?